# What happens when Java is deleting, editing and altering files in folder?

Tags: java

I have a java app that uses

```
File folder = new File("filesFolder);
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

    for(int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++){//check files and edit}
```

to go through each and every file in a folder with some specific instructions. What would happen if it is looping through the folder and new files are added? Would it process these new files or would they skipped?

This folder is constantly updated with new files to be processed.

Comment: Why don't use NIO2 on Java 7?

Comment: whats the benefit of using NIO2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New files (added after you call `listFiles()`) would be skipped. Additionally, if any files were deleted before they were processed, you'd get an Exception when you tried to read them.

This is because your array `listOfFiles` does not change. It's just an array of `File` objects. It's **not** somehow linked to the filesystem, unless you [implement that yourself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html).

Comment: _New files would be skipped._? Are you sure?

Comment: @PaulVargas I'm quite sure. He's not watching the directory for changes, so how could the program possibly be aware of new files added since the `listFiles()` call?

Comment: But it's looping individual files. Does java detect all the files then loop or just randomly start from the top? say file names were in order from 1 - 10 and then 11 was added when it was processing 9, shouldn't it be able to do 11?

Comment: @Dev-Ria Look at your code. You define a list of files by calling `folder.listFiles()`. This populates your array with `File` objects, which are abstractions created by Java. You then loop over this array. *At no time during your loop* do you update the list of files you're looping through. You need to either call `listFiles()` and look for changes on every iteration of the loop, or go visit the link in my answer and implement a `WatchService`.

Comment: How do I add WatchService to my current process? Do I need to rewrite the loop?

Comment: @Dev-Ria It's all laid out in the [tutorial I linked](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html#overview). You need a separate thread to watch for events, which will receive `WatchKey` objects and (presumably) pass filenames back to your processing code, e.g. by appending to a `synchronized List`.  A full implementation of this is way outside the scope of this site, but I encourage you to work through the tutorial and give it a shot, and if you get stuck, post a new question with the specific problem.

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help!